# Setup Auto Responders (Multiple Times)

Tags: outlook

I have set up a rule for my website that goes as follows:-

Apply this rule after the message arrives with 'Enquiry' in the subject or body reply using C:z\path-to-template-file

I'm really happy with how this works. The only thing is, this can only be sent once per sender. So if the sender makes more than one 'Enquiry', this e-mail is not automatically sent. I was wondering if someone could guide me on how to set up an additional rule that says something like:-

Apply this rule after the second message from a previous sender arrives with 'Enquiry' in the subject or body reply using C:z\path-to-template-file

I hope you can help

Comment: what do you think of my response, do you need some more information?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a rule with subject create a auto response including the sender along with "Enquiry" . This create a or condition such that outlook will send an autoresponse if a mail comes from that specified sender and contaning text as "Enquiry".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this reply. I don't know the sender though so this doesn't help

Comment: Sender in the sense you'll have a mailer Id or a mail ID from a specific company right? Without any mailing list no mail comes your mail so set a rule using that mail id and your subject.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you are looking for you would have to script the rule, luckily Outlook supports this although it's slightly more involved than the rule you have previously set up.  There are a number of ways to do this:

**Run a script from a rule**

One of the actions on rules is to run a script.  If you want to execute the rule as you are when the mail comes in then you can trigger some VBA code to perform the action you require. This will allow you to call a VBA procedure with the signature of:

```
Sub MyProcedure(myMailItem as Outlook.MailItem)
' your code to work with myMailItem goes here


End Sub
```

The advantage of doing the rule this way is they would get an immediate response to their message.  However if they sent two messages they would get a response for both.

**Process your inbox**

You can write some VBA that processes one of your mailboxes.
Microsoft have an article on [How to create a custom rule using VBA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/292063) which illustrates how a mailbox might be processed, although in this example it also processes incoming items.  This has the advantage that you can perform the action at a particular time, this means if you only want to send them a single email when they have sent multiple inquiries for a particular day you can.  This is because you can process the inbox for the day and count the emails from a particular sender and tailor the response as you need.

**Writing the rule**

What you will need to do is to store the senders you have already seen somewhere so you can determine whether to perform the action where they have sent you two emails. One interesting technique for you might be to store your inquiries in an Access database, then you can use it to track your leads.  There is some example code here [How do I export messages to Access](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-export-e-mail-messages-to-access-using-vba/).